# console.log of editorState on unfocus display a stack of all the changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

Please check in first place this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-buck-bpqwq?file=/src/App.tsx).

I wrote a `TextEditor` component using [draftjs](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js) that get 3 props:

- `text`: html as a string
- `onChange`: a callback that get a unique parameter (the updated html string)
- `onUnfocus`: a callback that is called when you click outside of the `TextEditor`

If you look in the `App` component where I use my `TextEditor` component, I store the text in a state that I update using `onChange`.

Clicking outside the `TextEditor` (with the blue background) will trigger the `onUnfocus` function that `console.log` the `text` state.

But If I write a word (let's say `Hello`) and then click outside the `TextEditor` I will get so many `console.log` as changes:

```
> H
> He
> Hel
> Hell
> Hello
```

The expected behavior would be to have a single `console.log` with the latest changes:

```
> Hello
```

Has someone an idea why I get so many `console.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you forgot to return your `useEffect` helper, and also didn't pass in `text` as a dependency, so the cleanup code is never called, so each time it renders it adds another `document.addEventListener` without ever removing the previous.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  return onClickOutsideHook( // add return here
    editorRef,
    (): void => {
      if (isFocus && onUnfocus !== undefined) {
        onUnfocus();
      }

      setIsFocus(false);
    }
  );
}, [editorState, isFocus, onUnfocus, text]); // add text as dependency
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ;) I never paid so much importance to the return function of `useEffect` but now that I will put more effort on it. By the way the link of your codesandbox don't contain the changes that you mentioned.